# Как записать в SharedPreferenses массив строк?

Tags: java, android

Как записать массив строк в `SharedPreferenses`, а потом его использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру, можно сделать так, если у вас массив(коллекция) примитивных типов.
Сохранение массива в Shared Preferences:

```
public static boolean saveArray(ArrayList<String> sKey, Context mContext)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = SharedPreferences.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();
    mEdit1.putInt("Status_size", sKey.size()); /* sKey - это массив */ 

    for(int i=0;i<sKey.size();i++)  
    {
        mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);
        mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i, sKey.get(i));  
    }

    return mEdit1.commit();     
}
```

Загрузка массива из Shared Preferences:

```
public static void loadArray(ArrayList<String> sKey, Context mContext)
{  
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    sKey.clear();
    int size = mSharedPreference1.getInt("Status_size", 0);  

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
    {
        sKey.add(mSharedPreference1.getString("Status_" + i, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Массив обычный, String, где каждый элемент имеет свое значение, P.S Значение любое, оно может сломать эти функции?

Comment: "Status_size" и "Status_" больше нигде не должны использоваться в Shared Preferences. А так нет, функции спокойно отработают для всех строк.

Comment: Тоесть можно эти два слова написать очень длинным не повторимым текстом так? А и пробую подставить sKey массив String[], говорит не знает что такое size()

Comment: Функции работают с коллекциями строк. Используйте ArrayList к примеру.

Comment: Да сообразил) подправьте код тогда свой, чтобы не по комментариям исправляли

Comment: Только я не понел, откуда во второй функции `load` появляется `sKey` а еще и `getInt` говорит не знает

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, что бы функции работали, нужно использовать ArrayList  к примеру. Тогда исправлять нечего.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, sKey - это ArrayList<String>, который у вас должен быть вне функций или же передаваться в них параметром.

Comment: Ну тогда напишите передачу sKey в loadArray, в виде аргументов

Comment: Готово. Пользуйтесь.)

Comment: Да, все работает!) задумка проста) но всеже работает)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант в JSON строку перегнать, а потом обратно.

Comment: Нет, ну это не ответ... Пример хотябы, ссылку... Вбил в поисковик куча бреда...

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, это дельный совет. еще есть хороший вариант конвернуть `ArrayList` в `Set` и `editor.putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)`.